# Trigger for a particular row?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I am trying to dynamically create a trigger for a **particular row** instead of for **each row**. So if a table has 1000 rows and I want notification only on 25 rows, I am creating triggers like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trig
AFTER UPDATE ON Sells
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (row_id="something")
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE sendNotif();
```

So with this only when my particular row is edited only then my sendNotif() is called.

Is this a good approach? Is there a benefit when compared to trigger on the whole table?

I am doing this because I want to send notifications only for rows which have a subscription.

**EDIT: Scenario explained:**

So I have two tables SELLS and SUBSCRIPTION. When a user wants to subscribe to sells resource (row), it creates a subscription resource (row). Once subscription resource is created, notification needs to sent whenever CRUD operations are performed to the subscribed-to (Sells) resource. So subscription resource is created once and after that notification is sent based on events (CRUD) on Sells resource. That is why trigger was on Sells resource to track it's changes.

Comment: Looks good to me because it limits the overhead of calling the trigger procedure to only the rows you are interested in (Btw: `row_id="something"` is invalid syntax. `"something"` refers to a column name, not a string literal)

Comment: It will be a valid column-value and row_id column-name. I added string just as dummy input

Comment: I understand what you _want_ to do, but your example will most definitely not run because `"something"` refers to a column named `something`

Comment: Ok. So what will be a valid syntax for mentioning a particular column's value to be xyz?

Comment: String literals need to be enclosed in **single** quotes: `when (row_id = 'foobar')`

Comment: You have not explained why you think you cannot change the table to accommodate the sensible solution which adds a column to the Sells table to record when there are subscriptions so that the special processing is needed.  Creating multiple triggers on a single table is a bad idea in most DBMS — I doubt if PostgreSQL is any better (or worse) than other DBMS.  Doing DDL operations as a result of a DML operation (a CREATE TRIGGER because someone does an INSERT, or a DROP TRIGGER because someone does a DELETE) is basically incorrect, and requires privileges that should not be widely available.

Comment: I agree with second part that multiple triggers on single table is a bad idea. What good would adding a column for notify do ?

Comment: Adding a column with a value to indicate whether the triggered procedure should be executed would save you from having to list a bunch of `row_id` values in your triggers, or otherwise doing DDL operations when a row is inserted into the database.